# SQL Records and Count

Tags: sql, count

Having trouble formatting SQL Quert to get records AND count.

```
SELECT
     eventStartDate
    ,eventTitle
    ,eventDesc
    ,eventTime
    ,count(eventID)
FROM GroupEvents 
WHERE eventStartDate = '10/14/2013'
GROUP BY eventStartDate
```

I would like to get back records so I can display like this...
(I can format - just showing you what I need)

```
There are 3 events for 10/14/2013   
    1. Dinner at Anthony's - 5:30pm
    2. Movie with New Members - 7:30pm
    3. Denny's - 11:00pm
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what is your specific problem?

Comment: Which RBDMS are you using?  MySql? Sql Server? Oracle?  The answer may vary based on your platform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can solve this with a Window Function:

```
SELECT
     eventStartDate
    ,eventTitle
    ,eventDesc
    ,eventTime
    ,count(eventID)over(partition by eventStartDate) as eventCount
FROM GroupEvents 
WHERE eventStartDate = '10/14/2013'
GROUP BY eventStartDate
```

Comment: +1 for the window function... perfect solution if he's on SQL Server.

Comment: I am using SQL Server. This worked great once I added the eventTitle, eventDesc, eventTime and eventID to the GROUP BY clause. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an RBDMS that doesn't support window functions, you'll need to determine the counts for each event date separately, and then join to this intermediate result to get the count AND the details for each event:

```
SELECT
     ge.eventStartDate
    ,ge.eventTitle
    ,ge.eventDesc
    ,ge.eventTime
    ,q.eventCount
FROM GroupEvents ge
JOIN (
    SELECT
         eventStartDate
        ,count(eventID) AS eventCount
    FROM GroupEvents 
    GROUP BY eventStartDate
) q ON q.eventStartDate = ge.eventStartDate
WHERE ge.eventStartDate = '10/14/2013'
```